# how to show images in laravel projects they stored in another laravel project in the same server

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have two laravel projects in the same server. one of them inside admin folder and the another one inside public_html
i can access my admin using the following url

```
https://mydomain/admin/public
```

then I can do all functionalities of admin without any problems but the another project inside public_html folder doesn't show images which stored in admin directory project
for example

```
https://example.com/admin/storage/app/public/logo.png
```

please note both projects read the same database and every thing works fine except showing uploaded images where I store them inside

```
https://example.com/admin/storage/app/public
```

I think I have errors in htaccess file or it doesn't configured well
this is .htaccess content inside public_html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

and this is APP_URL inside .env file

```
APP_URL=https://example.com/admin/
```

my question is what I should to change or add to show images from the project inside public_html which they are already inside admin project